# I am .5 off when trying to figure this out

Tags: python

```
x = 1 / 2 + 3 // 3 + 4 ** 2 # Why is this equivalent to 17?

y = 1 / 2 + 3 # This is equivalent to 3.5

z = 1 / 2 + 3 // 3 # This should be equivalent to 3.5 // 3

t = 3.5 // 3 + 4 ** 2 # Why is this 17 but the original statement is 17.5?
```

Why are the expressions for `t` and `x` providing different results? Are they not equivalent?

(Original image)

[image: Source from this image]

Comment: Perhaps we could better explain this if we had some slight idea as to why you think the answer is 17.

Comment: 80% of that is distracting fluff. You're really just asking why `1 / 2 + 3 // 3` is 1.5 instead of 1 like `3.5 // 3`. Please see [mre].

Comment: What Kelly said. Also, read about [**Operator Precedence**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). And in Jack's effort to make sense of your question, the `x` comment is incorrect - _"Why is this equivalent to 17?"_ should be _"Why is this equivalent to 17.5?"_

Answer (score 3):

It's 17.5 because your statement is as follows:

```
1/2 - this is evaluated to 0.5
3 // 3 - this is evaluated to 1
4 ** 2 - this is evaluated to 16
16 + 1 + 0.5 = 17.5
```

You need to understand the order of operations in your initial statement:

```
1 / 2 + 3 // 3 + 4 ** 2
```

This can be bracketed according to standard order of operations (BODMAS or some variant):

```
(1 / 2) + (3 // 3) + (4 ** 2)
```

Which then evaluates as above. Your confusion stems from the fact that `1 / 2 + 3 // 3` is not equivalent to `(1/2 + 3) // 3`, but instead equivalent to `(1/2) + (3 // 3)` - they're both division, so they'll both take precedence over the addition operator.